# Javascript Linking issue

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've been working on a courasel i think it's called or slider im trying link my js file but it isn't functioning and i can't put my finger on the issue. I'm trying to display pictures with the ability to move next and to previous with a click of a button; once the item is clicked their's a pop-out window supplied by "fancybox" js. i have downloaded a jquery library and saved it as "query.js"

```
<html>
<head> 
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="attempt2.css">

<script src="attempt2.js"></script>
</head>
<body>


<div class="gallery-wrap">
  <div class="gallery clearfix">
    <div class="gallery__item">
      <img src="images/image1.jpg" class="gallery__img" alt="" />
    </div>
     <div class="gallery__item">
      <img src="images/image2.jpg" class="gallery__img" alt="" />
    </div>
    <div class="gallery__item">
      <img src="images/image3.jpg" class="gallery__img" alt="" />
    </div>
    <div class="gallery__item">
      <img src="images/image4.jpg" class="gallery__img" alt="" />
    </div>
    <div class="gallery__item">
      <img src="images/image5.jpg" class="gallery__img" alt="" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="gallery__controls clearfix">
    <div href="#" class="gallery__controls-prev">
      <img src="images/prev.png" alt="" />
    </div>
    <div href="#" class="gallery__controls-next">
      <img src="images/next.png" alt="" />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="query.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="./fancybox/jquery.fancybox-1.3.1.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/fancybox/source/jquery.fancybox.css?v=2.1.5" type="text/css" media="screen"/>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/fancybox/source/jquery.fancybox.pack.js?v=2.1.5"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

    // Only run everything once the page has completely loaded
    $(window).load(function(){

        // Fancybox specific
        $(".gallery__link").fancybox({
            'titleShow'     : false,
            'transitionIn'  : 'elastic',
            'transitionOut' : 'elastic'
        });

        // Set general variables
        // ====================================================================
        var totalWidth = 0;

        // Total width is calculated by looping through each gallery item and
        // adding up each width and storing that in `totalWidth`
        $(".gallery__item").each(function(){
            totalWidth = totalWidth + $(this).outerWidth(true);
        });

        // The maxScrollPosition is the furthest point the items should
        // ever scroll to. We always want the viewport to be full of images.
        var maxScrollPosition = totalWidth - $(".gallery-wrap").outerWidth();

        // This is the core function that animates to the target item
        // ====================================================================
        function toGalleryItem($targetItem){
            // Make sure the target item exists, otherwise do nothing
            if($targetItem.length){

                // The new position is just to the left of the targetItem
                var newPosition = $targetItem.position().left;

                // If the new position isn't greater than the maximum width
                if(newPosition <= maxScrollPosition){

                    // Add active class to the target item
                    $targetItem.addClass("gallery__item--active");

                    // Remove the Active class from all other items
                    $targetItem.siblings().removeClass("gallery__item--active");

                    // Animate .gallery element to the correct left position.
                    $(".gallery").animate({
                        left : - newPosition
                    });
                } else {
                    // Animate .gallery element to the correct left position.
                    $(".gallery").animate({
                        left : - maxScrollPosition
                    });
                };
            };
        };

        // Basic HTML manipulation
        // ====================================================================
        // Set the gallery width to the totalWidth. This allows all items to
        // be on one line.
        $(".gallery").width(totalWidth);

        // Add active class to the first gallery item
        $(".gallery__item:first").addClass("gallery__item--active");

        // When the prev button is clicked
        // ====================================================================
        $(".gallery__controls-prev").click(function(){
            // Set target item to the item before the active item
            var $targetItem = $(".gallery__item--active").prev();
            toGalleryItem($targetItem);
        });

        // When the next button is clicked
        // ====================================================================
        $(".gallery__controls-next").click(function(){
            // Set target item to the item after the active item
            var $targetItem = $(".gallery__item--active").next();
            toGalleryItem($targetItem);
        });
    });
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you be a bit more specific about where you think you're having issues?

Comment: Please try to disect the problem a bit more, as it is currently unclear, what is your issue here.

Comment: the issue is fancy box isn't working and none of the javascript/jquery functionality

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your embedded script on your HTML page, you've referred Fancybox items as '.gallery__link' and you haven't used links to for Fancybox to use. So, where you've written:

```
<div class="gallery__item">
  <img src="images/image3.jpg" class="gallery__img" alt="" />
</div>
```

It should really be:

```
 <a href="images/image3.jpg" class="gallery__link">
  <img src="images/image3.jpg" />
</a>
```

[Here's a quick guide](http://fancybox.net/howto) on the Fancybox website of how to do different things:

*Don't hesitate to leave a comment if you need more help*

[Here's a link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BxS6l-qVL2-GdGhOMHl2bzJCTDA/edit?usp=sharing) to a really simple ZIP that contains a basic HTML page with the required links and Javascript.

Comment: Thanks for your answer i have made the changes you suggested but doesn't give the desired effect i want, this opens the image on a blank page. i am trying to get the image to pop out like the examples on [link](http://fancybox.net/) @Xanco

Comment: Hi there :) I've made a really simple ZIP file that contains all the tools you need to insert Fancybox, including a basic HTML page full of useful comments. Here's a link to it: http://goo.gl/zBiQOk just click 'file then 'download'. I'd be more than happy to help if you have any more issues :)

Comment: Thank you so much you went above and beyond. Much appreciated!

Comment: how would i go about linking two scripts both with an on load? @Xanco

Comment: Simply just link the script normally and it should work fine, assuming you're not using the same function names in both, here's the HTML:

<script type="text/javascript" src="yourfilehere"></script>